# WP8.1 Setting background property Style setter in c#

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a Windows Phone 8.1 application.
I am using c# code to try to change the value in the resource dicrionary.
so I try Style.setValue method, but it occur error.

```
    var selectedEllipseColor = (Ellipse)sender;
    SolidColorBrush selectedColor = (SolidColorBrush)selectedEllipseColor.Fill;
    String colorString = selectedColor.Color.ToString();   // Ex) #FFFFFF
    Style backgroundGridStyle = Application.Current.Resources["gridBackgroundStyle"] as Style;
    // ERROR!
    //backgroundGridStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Grid.BackgroundProperty, "red"));
    // ERROR too.
    backgroundGridStyle.SetValue(Grid.BackgroundProperty, selectedColor);
```

this is error message. : Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
backgroundGridStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Grid.BackgroundProperty,new SolidColorBrush( Colors.Red)));
```

use the above code, as you directly can't assign the value as string to color property.

For Example:

Even I got the same error while setting border brush /corner radius/border thickness for below border style:

```
Style x = this.Resources["BorderStyle"] as Style;

x.Setters.Add(new Setter(Border.CornerRadiusProperty, "25"));
x.Setters.Add(new Setter(Border.BorderThicknessProperty, "10"));
x.Setters.Add(new Setter(Border.BorderBrushProperty,"Red")));
```

But Update the Code like this:

```
Style x = this.Resources["BorderStyle"] as Style;
        x.Setters.Add(new Setter(Border.CornerRadiusProperty, new CornerRadius(25)));
        x.Setters.Add(new Setter(Border.BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(10)));
        x.Setters.Add(new Setter(Border.BorderBrushProperty,new SolidColorBrush( Colors.Red)));
```

It will resolve all of these issues.

Comment: Some example with explanation would be great.